# What are the differences in string initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, string, initialization

Is there any difference between

```
std::string s1("foo");
```

and

```
std::string s2 = "foo";
```

?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes and No.

The first is initialized explicitly, and the second is copy initialized. The standards permits to replace the second with the first. In practice, the produced code is the same.

Here is what happens in a nutshell:

```
std::string s1("foo");
```

The string constructor of the form:

```
string ( const char * s );
```

is called for `s1`.

In the second case. A temporary is created, and the mentioned earler constructor is called for that temporary. Then, the copy constructor is invoked. e.g:

```
string s1 = string("foo");
```

In practice, the second form is optimized, to be of the form of the first. I haven't seen a compiler that doesn't optimize the second case.

Comment: copy constructor will not be invoked in the second case, only string ( const char * s ) is called. That's copy initialization. Check: [how-c-implicitly-convert-c-style-string-to-a-string-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568612/how-c-implicitly-convert-c-style-string-to-a-string-object)

Answer (score 13):

On the face of it, the first one calls the `const char*` constructor to initialize `s1`. The second one uses the `const char*` constructor to initialize a temporary value, and then uses the copy constructor, passing in a reference to that temporary value, to initialize `s2`.

However, the standard explicitly permits something called "copy elision", which means that as AraK says, the second can legally be replaced with the first *even if the copy constructor has observable side-effects*, so that the change affects the output of the program.

However, when this replacement is done, the compiler must still check that the class has an accessible copy constructor. So a potential difference is that the second form requires a copy constructor to be callable, even though the compiler doesn't have to call it. Obviously `std::string` does have one, so in this case that doesn't make a difference, but for other classes it could.

Comment: You got my +1 for "the standard explicitly permits something called "copy elision" ;)

Comment: Minor confession: after posting I noticed it's "copy constructor elision" in the index, but as far as I remember I've referred to it as "copy elision" :-)

Answer (score 3):

there's no difference

Answer (score -5):

The first one is better.

The second one will create the instance and will assign the default value (""). Then there will be a secodn assignement : "foo".
So 2 assignments instead of 1...

Comment: No, the second one does not call the assignment operator.