# how C++ Implicitly convert c style string to a string object?

Tags: c++, string

```
string s = "abc";
```

The above statement will first invoke `string ( const char * s )` constructor, then invoke copy constructor according to [What are the differences in string initialization in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192238/what-are-the-differences-in-string-initialization-in-c) .
Here is the question: how C++ know it should invoke `string ( const char * s )` to convert literal string "abc" to a temporary string object?

**Note**:
copy constructor won't be invoked in copy initialization.

Comment: It runs overload resolution on all of the converting constructors of the destination type `std::string` (and any non-explicit conversion functions of the source type, if it's a class type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializing an object by using the syntax

```
string s = "abc";
```

is called [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

There are several scenarios where that is legal initialization. In all cases the RHS must be convertible to a `string` for it to work.

One way a string literal can be converted to a `string` is through the constructor of `string` that takes a `char const*`. That is called a [user defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast).

Answer (score 1):

Summary of all answers:

Reference:

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast
2. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization
3. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor